# alltool: The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value

Tags: notarize

I'm trying to upload an .ipa with altool, but it doesn't accept the `apple-id` argument    --apple-id id.

```
xcrun altool --upload-package \
    MyApp.ipa \
    --type ios \
    --asc-public-id $ASC_PUBLIC_ID \
    --apple-id me@gmail.com \
    --bundle-version 100 \
    --bundle-short-version-string 1.0 \
    --bundle-id com.myco.myapp \
    --apiKey $APPLE_ID_KEY_ID \
    --apiIssuer $APPLE_ID_ISSUER_ID \
    --show-progress
```

It errors out with:

```
The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value 'me@gmail.com' is not a valid ID for this relationship.
```

The altool documentation says that apple-id is the "ID of the app":

```
--apple-id id
                  Specify the Apple ID of the app to be uploaded with --upload-package.
```

Is that something different from my Apple ID used to sign into Apple Developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *app* Apple ID is under General/App Information, in App Store Connect.